# How to restrict the expressions eval() or exec() can run?

Tags: python, parsing

So I'm trying to make a Python app that's sort of like a set theory calculator (i.e. the union of two sets, intersection, complement, etc.).  I want to have a text field that, when executed, is evaluated like Python expressions, with braces and all turned into sets.  When the new sets are computed, the result will be printed on-screen.  However, I want to make sure the user doesn't enter any Python commands that may screw the whole app (or worse; system) up, whether intentionally or not.  He should only be able to enter the following;

- Set operations (union, difference, cardinality, etc; I will provide buttons for the math symbols and use regexes to make it proper under the hood)
- Sets (which, in turn, can only hold the following elements; other sets, tuples, integers, real numbers, alphabetic characters, and strings).

To give you an idea, this is what input and output should look like (this app will be with a GUI, I just use terminal style for convenience):

```
>>> {1, 2, a} - {a}
{1, 2}
```

Any tips?  Or should I just implement a mini-language which I turn into Python commands?

Comment: Letting the user enter arbitrary code is seriously risky...http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/programming-is-hard-lets-go-shopping.html

Comment: If you *"trust"* the users (e.g. it runs on *their machine* under *their credentials*) .. then let them do as they wish. Buyer beware and all. However, if you wish to write/use/allow only a specific DSL, then by all means, handle only a specific DSL - grammar parsing and all (but use tools to help :).

Comment: Domain Specific Language

Comment: OK, what tools for my own DSL might you recommend?  (I have some background in regexes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with the mini language that you can translate into python commands.

If you want to represent sets with {} notation, you would just make sure that every non-numeric value contained within the brackets is treated like a string (to avoid security risks). Nested brackets would be instantiated as frozen sets as sets are unhashable and cannot be nested.

Operands between parsed sets should probably be limited to:

```
s <= t  test whether every element in s is in t
s >= t  test whether every element in t is in s
s | t   new set with elements from both s and t
s & t   new set with elements common to s and t
s - t   new set with elements in s but not in t
s ^ t   new set with elements in either s or t but not both
```

Comment: I'll probably go with the mathematical notation (with the aid of an on-screen keyboard).  But since I don't have any data structures background, I'll probably just stick with this for now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Compile](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#compile) the expression first, then [walk the resultant AST](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) to verify that it only contains operations you explicitly want to allow. *Then* [evaluate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) it.

Comment: What do you mean by walking, exactly?  I haven't taken a data structures class yet, so please bear with me.

Comment: The most comprehensive approach +1.

Comment: @JesseTG: The "T" is AST is for "tree". You need to bounce up and down the branches in order to parse the tree.